# Functionality difference between application that has 'internal'/'external' daemon threads

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

Is there a difference in thread operation functionality between an *application with 3 daemon threads that all pull from a multiprocessing Queue* and *4 separate applications: a multiprocessing Queue/Pipe and 3 daemon thread applications that read from the Queue/Pipe application*?

Neither application uses blocking/synchronisation. At the end of the day the operating system will decide when to allow a thread to run and for how long. Are there any other differences in functionality here or are they essentially the same?

> Generic Application (no synchronisation or blocking):
>
> > - 'Stock Market Feed' Queue: StockTrade messages (dictonaries)
> > - 'TradingStrategy' 1 Daemon Thread: Pull from queue, inspect messages and perform trades
> > - 'TradingStrategy' 1 Daemon Thread: Pull from queue, inspect messages and perform trades
> > - 'TradingStrategy' 1 Daemon Thread: Pull from queue, inspect messages and perform trades

Alternate architecture:

> Feed Application (no multi-threading):
>
> > - 'Stock Market Feed' Queue or Pipe: StockTrade messages (dictonaries). Can a Queue be accessed from another *outside* process? I know a named pipe can but can a queue?
>
> Trading Application (no multi-threading):
>
> > - 'TradingStrategy': Interacts with feed (pipe?/queue), inspect messages and perform trades
>
> Trading Application (no multi-threading):
>
> > - 'TradingStrategy': Interacts with feed (pipe?/queue), inspect messages and perform trades
>
> Trading Application (no multi-threading):
>
> > - 'TradingStrategy': Interacts with feed (pipe?/queue), inspect messages and perform trades

Comment: In the alternate arch, are they threads? or processes?

Comment: @JohnMee No each application currently uses no multi-threading. I'll update the question to show that.

Comment: So you're asking if there is a difference between running one process with four threads, or four processes with one thread each?

Comment: @JohnMee yes thats correct

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two options are quite different. But it gets complicated fast trying to explain the difference.  You should research and read up on the differences between a thread and a process.  Get that in your head straight first.

Now, given your specific scenario, assuming by "multiprocessing queue" you actually mean an instance of a python Queue in one thread of a process, since the queue is inside the same process as all the worker threads, the workers will be able to access, and share that same instance of the Queue.

However when the workers are all separate processes then they cannot access the Queue by shared memory and will need some form of interprocess communication to gain access to that queue.

In practice, I'd be thinking something like [redis](http://redis.io) or [zeromq](http://zeromq.org) to be your queue, then build a python program to talk to it, then scale up as few, or as many copies of it, as you need.

Comment: thanks, do you know if its possible to have a full-duplex named pipe with 1 writer (Market Feed) and 3 readers (Trading Strategy apps)? Also considering dbus or dbus glib.

Comment: @JakeM sorry, no idea, I'd just be googling and trying to interpret for you. But I will say the multiprocessing library of python is not that scary, just start playing with it and see what you can/can't do.  One thing to appreciate is that it works by pickling/serializing everything, which shapes what you can/can't do.